# Silencing Constraint Warnings in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I always get this huge constraint warning that clutters my console when I enter a certain view. I realize my constraints are probably off but everything displays the way I want it to without any storyboard or compile-time warnings.

So is there a way to get rid of this big annoying message?

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-08-05 15:26:27.151[APP][12834:12179015] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef7529660 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffef75294b0(94)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef752a220 H:[UILabel:0x7ffef752a020'Mahi Mahi Filet Fresh'(432)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef752d470 UIImageView:0x7ffef75294b0.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffef7529370.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef752d790 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffef75294b0]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7ffef752a020'Mahi Mahi Filet Fresh']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef752dc90 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffef7529370.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7ffef752c180'07/07'.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef752dce0 H:[UILabel:0x7ffef752a020'Mahi Mahi Filet Fresh']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7ffef752c180'07/07']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef75351b0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffef7529370(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffef752a220 H:[UILabel:0x7ffef752a020'Mahi Mahi Filet Fresh'(432)]>
```

Comment: I *strongly* suggest you fix that instead of suppressing the warnings... they are there for a reason.

I myself could not find a way to suppress tem for the sake of curiosity, but on Xcode you could try "Select your project -> Build Settings -> Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options -> Show Warnings -> "NO""